# clojure definition of list in source code

Tags: clojure

I was browsing the clojure source code this morning, and near the top of `clojure/core.clj` I found this:

```
(def
    ^{:arglists '([& items])
      :doc "Creates a new list containing the items."
      :added "1.0"}
    list (. clojure.lang.PersistentList creator))
```

The thing that looks odd to me is the symbol `creator`. It doesn't appear anywhere in the file above it. Why is that not a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dot special form is used for [java interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop). Since `clojure.lang.PersistentList` is a class name symbol,

```
(. clojure.lang.PersistentList creator)
```

is an access of the static `creator` field.

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java#L66

Comment: Im used to seeing `clojure.lang.PersistentList/creator` for static access, so that threw me off. Thanks.

Comment: This function was written before the `Foo/bar` syntax was added to the language.